# MongoDB - Querying nested documents automatically

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm wondering if there is any annotation or special method that I can use to query nested documents automatically. I have a class `Queue` that has a list of items. When querying a queue, I'd like to retrieve the items related to it, but I'm getting null.

```
public class Queue 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I'm querying a queue by its id using the following command:

```
var filter = Filter.Eq(queue => queue.Id, queueId);
return Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Is it an automatic way to do that or I need to go manually and query the item list based on the code above?

Thank y'all!

Comment: What's in your database? Without the explicit use of a projection MongoDB will return the entire document which would include your items if they are present. Or have you got any custom mapping set up?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
 public async Task<List<Item>> GetItemsFromQueue(string queueId)
 { 
    return await Collection.Find(queue => queue.Id == queueId)
        .Project(new ProjectionDefinitionBuilder<Queue>().Expression(q => q.Items))
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```